# Understanding routing in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok first off I have to say I'm very new to Rails. I have spent the last few days going through tutorial after tutorial and still missing a few concepts. Mainly because I just want to start off with a simple site structure but every tutorial is either a shopping cart or a blog which are more applications within a site. I have some pages on my site that will have photo galleries that are database driven but for now I'm just trying to get some answers to these questions.

Site structure:

> *home | photos | about | work | contact*

Work has sub pages for example:

> *html | ruby | rails | bla-bla*

- **Controllers**:

Do I need to set up a controller for every new page or could I have one controller that handles all main level pages. 
If I could use one controller how would that work and would I need to define an action to handle each page ( view ) like

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def photos
  end

  def contact
  end

  # and so on ......
end
```

- **Routing:**

How would I route the above. 
Whats the difference between a *resource* and a *get

- get  "photos/photos"
- resources  :photos

When I setup a controller for a specific page like. 
rails g controller Contact contact

It creates a folder inside my views called contact and inside it is a view called contact meaning my url is contact/contact
it also adds a route get "contact/contact" 
Now what if I only want the user to type `http://mydomain/contact` then this is not going to work. How would I set it up so the user doesn't have to add `http://mydomain/contact/contact`
The only way I could find a way around this was to use the match verb.

```
match "contact" => 'contact#contact'
```

Does this mean I have to use the match for every page on my site to change the url path?

These are just a few of many question I have that are not so clear in most of the tutorials I have gone over. Please don't tell me to use the user guide as I have already and am felling overwhelmed right now. I just would love some clear answers from some developers who are working in rails and would go about setting up a structure like I have outlined above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to get some conflicting advice I think, but here's what I'd do.

- Create a MainController (I prefer HomeController as it will also handle the homepage, but that's just me).  This controller will handle the actions for home, about, and contact.
- Create a PhotosController since you said photos come from the database and there's a good chance there is an index/listing page and individual pages for each photo.
- Create a WorksController that handles the work main page and all the sub pages.

Now.. some people would argue (myself included) that home, about, contact, and all the work pages (sub pages too) should be handled by a generic PagesController that is smart enough to know what to do.  I'm not gonna get into that now though.

The difference between these two routes:

```
get "photos/photos"
resources :photos
```

Is that the first will only create a *single* route for a GET request to '/photos/photos'.  The second will create the standard CRUD operations for '/photos'.

For your static pages, I probably would go ahead and just create:

```
match "about" => 'main#about'
match "contact" => 'main#contact'
...
```

It's harder to say for the photos and work since I don't know what all you'll be doing there.  The above isn't as DRY as it could be, but unless you go the "smart pages controller" route it's the simplest.

Comment: Thanks Philip this really helps. I would defiantly be interested in knowing how one would setup a PagesController that could handle all pages. I was also thinking of something like that but thought that would be the same as having to put an action definition for each view like I outlined above in my post. This defeats the purpose because I would be repeating code. So in your code would HomeController work like I had MainController. Would I need to put action definitions for about, contact & index inside that HomeController to handle rendering of each individual view

Comment: If about/contact/index are just straight views, nothing fancy, you can cheat and leave out the action method in the controller.  However, doing so also means that any before/after filters won't get called so it's a good idea to include them.

Comment: For the PagesController, create that controller with an :index action method and then add this to the end of your routes file (but before the default route if you still have that in place): https://gist.github.com/4178245  then experiment with it as you hit various urls and see what you get and how you could handle it.